# How to produce list of variables when ExpandAll is used beforehand?

Tags: coefficients

I am having an issue with `Variables[]` and `Coefficient[]` functions. I have a very long expression obtained where I utilize `//ExpandAll`. When I execute `Variables[%]` right after that expression I get `{ExpandAll}` instead of the list of variables in the expression. Thus, I cannot get a specific coefficient. Probably this is a basic issue to tackle but I couldn't and really don't understand what's going on here. Here is the code I have:

```
xtRule=x[t]-> \[Alpha][0]+\[Alpha][1] x[t-1]+\[Alpha][2] (E1)[t]+\[Alpha][3]y[t-4]-\[Alpha][4](z[t-1]-z[t-2]-x[t-1]+fx[t-1])+\[Epsilon][t]; (* fx stands for foreign x *)
ytRule=y[t]-> \[Beta][0]+\[Beta][1] y[t-1]+\[Beta][2] y[t-2]+\[Beta][3](E2)[t]-\[Beta][4](i[t-2]-(E3)[t])-\[Beta][5](z[t-1]-z[t-2]-x[t-1]+fx[t-1])+\[Eta][t];
ztRule=z[t]-> \[Phi][1]z[t-1]+\[Phi][2](E4)[t]+\[Phi][3](i[t-1]-fi[t-1])+\[Upsilon][t]; (* fi stands for foreign i *)
itRule=i[t]-> \[Rho] i[t-1]+(1-\[Rho] )(\[Gamma][0]+\[Gamma][1](E1)[t]+\[Gamma][2](E5)[t]+\[Gamma][3]y[t-5]+\[Gamma][4]y[t-6]+\[Gamma][5](E2)[t]+\[Sigma][t]); (* This is rather a general itRule for all periods *)

getClosestT[Rule[from_,to_]]:=(to/.{x[a_]:>Sow[a],y[a_]:>Sow[a],z[a_]:>Sow[a],i[a_]:>Sow[a]}//Reap//Last//Flatten//Union//Last)

applyMultTimesTo[rule_,num_]:=Nest[(#/.({xtRule,ytRule, ztRule, itRule}/.t->getClosestT[#])//ExpandAll//Collect[#,{x[_],y[_],i[_],z[_]}]&)&,rule,num]

xx=applyMultTimesTo[xtRule,3]// ExpandAll/ Collect[#,{x[_],y[_],z[_],i[_], \[Epsilon][_], \[Eta][_], \[Upsilon][_],\[Sigma][_], fi[_], fx[_], E1[_], E2[_], E3[_], E4[_], E5[_]},FullSimplify]&

In[54]:= Variables[%]

Out[54]= {ExpandAll}

In[56]:= Variables[xx]

Out[56]= {ExpandAll}

In[55]:= Coefficient[%, i[t - 4]]

Out[55]= {0}
```

Comment: You are missing a `/` between `ExpandAll` and `Collect[` in your `xx` expression. The leftover `/` is then interpreted as a division.

Comment: Thank you Marco for pointing out the typo. I corrected my code but still cannot get the list of variables and coefficients. After correcting the `/`, both `Variables[xx]` and `Variables[%]` gives `{}`. Why am not given the list of variables instead? Thanks.

Comment: `Variables` wants to act on a polynomial, but `xx` is a `Rule`.  Try this:  `Variables[xx//Last]`

Comment: Thank you @LouisB. 'Variables[xx//Last]' works perfectly. Best,